# A review of 2D Topological Gravity and Topological Strings

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, topological-field-theory

I am interested in a modern review on the subject. There is [a famous review by Dijkgraaf, Verlinde and Verlinde](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0ba5/59045060d32e5c88e424d09eb332021b9512.pdf), but it is 27 years old. What I am particularly interested in is a theory on manifolds with boundaries.